# Understanding why $\pi_{3}(N) = \mathbb{Z}_{(2n, n^2)}$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, projective-geometry

I am trying to understand the paper [Arkowitz and Golasinski - Co-$H$ structures on Moore spaces of type $(G, 2)$](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1994-037-0):

> [image: Arkowitz and Golasinski - Co-H-structures on Moore spaces of type (G, 2), p. 673]

In section 4, titled "Homotopy elements of finite order", the authors say $\pi_{3}(N) = \mathbb{Z}_{(2n, n^2)}$ and reference Lemma 1 in [Sieradski - Stabilization of self-equivalences of the pseudoprojective spaces](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029000840):

> [image: Sieradski - Stabilization of self-equivalences of the pseudoprojective spaces, p. 109]

which is:

> [image: Lemma 1 of "Stabilization of self-equivalences of the pseudoprojective spaces"]

**Lemma 1**.  The group $\pi_3(\mathbb P_q^2)$ is cyclic of order $(2q, q^2)$.  Moreover, the suspension homomorphism $\Sigma : \pi_2(\mathbb P_q^1) \to \pi_3(\mathbb P_q^2)$ sends the $\pi_1$-generator of $\pi_2(\mathbb P_q^1)$ to $q$ times a generator of $\pi_3(\mathbb P_q^2)$.

But I do not understand how this lemma leads to that result, could anyone explain that for me, please?

Comment: Please don't make a post consisting just of pictures; all else aside, it destroys any text-based work flows.  I have edited in the paper titles and the text of the relevant result (as best I could read it), but that's something you should be doing yourself.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to tell us that in the first paper, $N$ is notation for $M(\mathbb Z/n, 2)$.

Comment: If you're asking why Sieradski's Lemma 1 applies in this case, the answer is that $\mathbb P_n^2$ is a Moore space $M(\mathbb Z/n, 2)$: $\mathbb P_n^2$ is defined by attaching a $3$-cell to $S^2$ via a degree-$n$ map, so when one computes using the CW chain complex, $\tilde H_2(\mathbb P_n^2)\cong\mathbb Z/n$ and all other homology vanishes. Thus, by definition, $\mathbb P_n^2$ is the homotopy type $M(\mathbb Z/n, 2)$ that Arkowitz-Golasinski need. Alternatively, was your question about the proof of Lemma 1 in Sieradski's paper?

Comment: @ArunDebray No Arun just the statement .... thank you so much for your clarification.

Comment: @TimCampion Sorry about that Tim, I will be more clear in my next posts :)

Comment: @LSpice Thank you so much LSpice ..... I promise I will take care of that next time.